# What is the steps to generate data from a plot and use them to have a predication using python?

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, data-science-model, feature-extraction, data-analysis

I have a plot that represent a BH curve for magnatic material. The material have a behavior for each H value for two different temperature 25 C and 100 C. Figure 1. I need to extract the data for each plot separately and generate just one plot for each temperature as in green line in figure 2. In addition, the dotted red line represents a missing data which has end at Bm = 0.49 at 15 Oe.

**I need recommendation which packages and models in python I can use in python to extract the data , generate the green line from the available data, and predict the missing data ( red line) using known stop point, and represent the data in a table**

[image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: How many of those plots do you have?

Comment: @Broele I have the original one Figure 2-14. I used iPad to modify the plot and seperate each curve by itself based on the temerature. So I jave the orginial figuer and two more ( total three.